# Sitecore: pass language information with menu item command/message

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, sitecore, sitecore8, message-handlers

I'm working with Sitecore 8 Update 2.

I have extended the default TreelistEx class with my own.
I've added a menu item that sends out the following message:

```
mytreelistex:myadd(id=$Target)
```

I would like to know what language the item is that the user is currently working on ( so the language of the item that contains this custom field )

I tried adding `language=$language` to the message but this just returns as plain text unlike the `id=$Target`

[image]

Does anyone know how i can achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

A colleague of mine pointed out that TreelistEx has an ItemLanguage property that i can use.

Sitecore.Context was no help, it looks like all context is lost when the message arrives server-side.